# Flask jinja2 cannot find the HTML template

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I was following the [Flask Quickstart guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#rendering-templates). about rendering templates, and I think I am doing exactly what the guide says:

Here is my Python code:

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello/')
@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('hello.html', name=name)
```

And my `hello.html` template looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Hello from Flask</title>
{% if name %}
  <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
{% else %}
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

And I have put that html file in my templates folder:

[image]

Now, when I browse to `http://localhost:5000/hello/hey` I get the `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound` error.

It seems I am missing something obvious here, but I don't understand what as I just started learning Flask.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be putting any of your own code under site-packages.

Comment: May I ask why? And where should I put my `hello.html` file? In the Flask quickstart guide it says _Flask will look for templates in the templates folder. So if your application is a module, this folder is next to that module, if it’s a package it’s actually inside your package._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be manually putting code in `site-packages`, and especially not putting it in other libraies' directories.  You seem to have misunderstood the quickstart, and thought to search for an existing folder called `templates` to put your code in.  This is wrong.  You create your app completely separately from the env, and create the templates folder next to it.

```
/project  # your stuff goes in this folder
    /env  # do not touch this folder
    app.py
    /templates
        index.html
```